# How to sequentially number data populated by a Userform

Tags: vba, sequential-number

I am a real newbie and have been searching on here for help but cannot find what I'm after.

I have created a user form that populates data into a target worksheet, I need it to sequentially number each row of data and ensure that every time I transfer data it continues the numbering where it left off.

I do not know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you correctly. Here is what the macro does.

[image]

When you try it remember to make changes to the config area of the code.

```
Sub NumberSequence()

Dim input_one As String, input_two As String, input_three As String
Dim target As String, main As String, col_start As String
Dim col_start_number As Long, substract As Long
Dim next_row As Long, next_number As Long

'CONFIG HERE
'---------------------------------------
'ranges of form inputs
input_one = "B3"
input_two = "C3"
input_three = "D3"

'first column where data starts in target sheet
col_start = "A"

'from what row do you want to start counting?
substract = 3

'names of sheets
target = "target"
main = "form"
'---------------------------------------

'convert the letter of the column to a number
col_start_number = Range(col_start & 1).Column

'get next empty row in target sheet
next_row = _
Sheets(target).Cells(Rows.Count, col_start_number).End(xlUp).row + 1

'next number in the sequence
next_number = next_row - substract + 1

With Sheets(target)
    
    'transfer the sequencial number
    .Cells(next_row, col_start_number) = next_number
    
    'transfer the inputs of the form
    .Cells(next_row, col_start_number + 1) = _
    Sheets(main).Range(input_one)

    .Cells(next_row, col_start_number + 2) = _
    Sheets(main).Range(input_two)
    
    .Cells(next_row, col_start_number + 3) = _
    Sheets(main).Range(input_three)

End With

End Sub
```